# html appending url for form action

Tags: html

on my html page I do form action after a button has been pressed:

```
<form action="/example.php" method="POST">
```

how do I append that url so I can use input from a textbox as well?
what I want to do is redirect user to a specific url

```
/example.php?id=inputfromtextbox
```

Comment: Are you trying to mix `POST` and `GET` method ? (hint: it's not a good idea, but it could work...)

Comment: yeah I want to POST from html and I already GET from php. Don't really care as long as it works, otherwise I would've used a database

Comment: If you already have the value, then just echo it in an `<input type=hidden>` into the POST form

Comment: how do I do that and add it in with the base url? sorry, im not any good at html

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">`

Comment: <form action="/example.php" +  'textbox'.value method="POST"> is what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

With php you can directly interpret the value from the textbox that you have just by accessing it with post:

```
$textVal = $_POST["someInput"];
```

And even redirect to another page with a constructed url:

```
header("Location:example2.php?id=$textVal");
```

But it's not a very good idea, because if you already have the value just use it.

With Javascript you can directly navigate to the url you want when the user submits the form. First you must handle the form submission with the onsubmit event:

```
<form id="form1" action="/example.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitFunc()">
```

Then in the function you would do:

```
function submitFunc(){
     var textVal = document.getElementById("someInput").value;
     var formAction = document.getElementById("form1").getAttribute("action");
     window.location.href= formAction + "?id=" + textVal;
     return false;
}
```

The simplest of all would actually be to change the method type to GET which would already encode the form values in the url itself.